# What is the distribution of the sqrt of a random variable with exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ be a random variable with an exponential distribution where: 
>   $f(x) = e^{-x}$ for all $x \geq 0$ (i.e. $X \sim \textrm{Exp}(\lambda = 1)$). Calculate >the distribution of $Y = X^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

I tried to do the following thing:
$P(X=k)=\int_0^k e^{-x}dx=-e^{-x}|_0^k=1-e^{-k}$.

So, $P(X^{\frac{1}{2}}=k)=P(X=k^2)=\int_0^{k^2} e^{-x}dx=-e^{-x}|_0^{k^2}=1-e^{-k^2}$.

I think that if I differentiate this function by $k$, I should get the distribution (am I right?). So, I get:

$(1-e^{-k^2})'_k = 2ke^{-k^2}$. I get that for $Y=X^{\frac{1}{2}}$, 
$f(y)=2ye^{-y^2}$. But I don't think this is the expected answer since it is not any known distribution.

Where was I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The idea is good, the way you work it out is not. $\mathbb{P}(X=k)=0$ if $X$ is a continuous probability distribution, e.g. an exponential random variable. You need to word with CDF, see my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume that $X \sim \textrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ and let $Y = \sqrt{X}$. For any $y \geq 0$ we have

$\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(\sqrt{X} \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq y^2) = 1- e^{-\lambda y^2}$.

Note that in the second equality we have used in a crucial way the fact that an exponential random variable is supported on $[0,+\infty)$. The pdf of $Y$ can then be calculated by differentiating the CDF obtained above:

$ f_Y(y) = 2 \lambda y e^{-\lambda y^2} \mathrm{1}_{[0,\infty)}(y)$.

Comment: I see. Thank you!!

Comment: @Ale Shouldn't it be $f_Y(y)=2\lambda ye^{-\lambda y^2}$? I.e. $y$ instead of $y^2$?

Comment: @Mick Correct, I edited my answer.

Comment: @alezok, could you please explain how you could derive the equality $\mathbb{P}(\sqrt{X} \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq y^2)$? So, it's true in general $\mathbb{P}(Z \leq z) = \mathbb{P}(Z^n \leq z^n)$ where $n$ is a real value, isn't it? Also, you said you would edit your answer to show $ f_Y(y) = 2 \lambda y e^{-\lambda y^2} $ as suggested by Mick, but it still shows $ f_Y(y) = 2 \lambda y e^{-\lambda y^2} \mathrm{1}_{[0,\infty)}(y)$? What does $\mathrm{1}_{[0,\infty)}(y)$ mean? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nemo, $X$ is a non-negative random variable (by definition) and by writing the event $\sqrt{X} \leq y$ we tacitly assume that $y \geq 0$ and thus $\sqrt{X} \leq y$ is equivalent $X \leq y^2$ by "taking the square on both sides". The general statement is not true in general, it depends on the assumptions on the random variable $Z$ and on the scalar $z$. Mike was only correcting a typo in the exponent of my expression, the correct expression should still have the indicator function $\mathrm{1}_{[0,\infty)}(y)$ which is simply equal to $1$ if $y\in [0,\infty)$ (i.e. $y \geq 0$) and $0$ otherwise

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, @alezok. From my understanding, user135172 did manage to derive the correct distribution ($f(y)=2ye^{-y^2}$) because $\lambda$ = 1 in this case. If so, why didn't he think his derivation was expected because it *was not any known distribution*, but then he accepted your answer (which is essentially the same)? Also, why did we need to have the indicator function? Without it, the expression $f_Y(y)=2\lambda ye^{-\lambda y^2}$ is still a distribution function wouldn't it? Do we need to prove integration of $f_Y(y)=2\lambda ye^{-\lambda y^2}$ converges to 1?