# Prove the two random variables are independent and have standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

Let $\alpha\sim U(0,2\pi),R\sim \textrm{Exp}(0.5)$ be independent. Prove $X=\sqrt R \cos\alpha$ and $Y=\sqrt R \sin \alpha$ are independent and have standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$.

It is easy to find the distributions and densities of $\sqrt R,\sin\alpha,\cos \alpha$:[$\sqrt R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1512756/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-sqrt-of-a-random-variable-with-exponential-distr),[$\sin\alpha$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026366/distribution-of-sine-of-uniform-random-variable-on-0-2-pi). But I have difficulty finding the densities of $X$ and $Y$, as I come across an integral I don't know how to solve.

How to proceed?

Comment: Whatever that integral is, try typing it into the [Approach0 search engine](https://www.approach0.xyz) and see what you get. It may be possible that it is already there.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Thanks, it works!

Comment: Oh hey, I'm happy it worked @RoteNino. Perhaps it's down to your persistence , and you searched well, but that was quick!